# Returning all columns from one of the tables in the LINQ join

Tags: c#, linq

Is it possible to return all the columns from one of the tables in the join statement in either LINQ to SQL or LINQ to EF?

I am joining together two tables *PctmMember* and *PclmMember*. They have exactly the same structure except the TM table is this months members and the LM table is last months. I am joining them by *SocSecNo* and using a number of where clauses to filter the rows i want. But in the end i want all columns from the TM table and none from the LM table.

Comment: select r1 from TM join r2 in LM on r1.SocSecNo equals r2.SocSecNo where r2.col="foo" select r1;

Comment: shouldn't it start with `from` ? @TimSchmelter never seen a linq that starts with `select`.

Comment: @Aniket: yes, of course.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
from t1 in dbContext.PctmMember
join t2 in dbContext.PclmMember on t1.SocSecNo equals t2.SocSecNo
select t1
```